# MongoDB $elemMatch projection on Nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection (summary) like this.

```
    {
    "id":"summaryid",
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": "loc1",
            "datacenters": [
                {
                    "id": "dc1.1",
                    "clusters": [
                        {
                            "id": "cl1.1",
                            "servers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "srvr1.1",
                                    "services": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "srvc1.1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "dc1.2",
                    "clusters": [
                        {
                            "id": "cl1.2",
                            "servers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "srvr1.2",
                                    "services": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "srvc1.2"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "loc2",
            "datacenters": [
                {
                    "id": "dc2.1",
                    "clusters": [
                        {
                            "id": "cl2.1",
                            "servers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "srvr2.1",
                                    "services": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "srvc2.1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "dc2.2",
                    "clusters": [
                        {
                            "id": "cl2.2",
                            "servers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "srvr2.2",
                                    "services": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "srvc2.2"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want only the clusters that are for datacenter with id dc1.1. I would like to exclude servers for the clusters.

I have tried using find query with $elemMatch and projections as below.

```
db.summary.find({}, {"locations": { $elemMatch: { "datacenters._id" : 
"dc1.1" } }, "locations.datacenters.clusters":0, 
"locations.datacenters.servers":0, "locations.datacentercount" : 0, 
"locations.clustercount" : 0, "locations.servercount" : 0}).pretty()
```

I am still getting all the datacenters instead of just 1 that matches the id. 
I am not sure if I am doing this right.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your expected json result? are you hoping for just { "id": "dc1.1", "clusters": [ {"id": "cl1.1",} ] }

Comment: Your `$elemMatch` instruction is using `"datacenters._id"` but the correct path (based on the example document you supplied) is `"datacenters.id"`

Comment: `find` is to find documents, not parts of the documents. Projection applies to all properties unconditionally, and is not the right tool here. You need to use aggregation to retrieve sub-documents.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I tried the aggregations and was get what I want. Following is what I am using. 
 `
 db.summary.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$locations"},
   {"$unwind": "$locations.datacenters"},
   { $match: { "locations.datacenters._id" : "dc1.1" } },
   { $project : {"locations.datacenters.servers" : 0, "locations.datacenters.clusters.servers" : 0} }
 ]).pretty()
 `

Comment: New challenge is that I am using spring-mongodb-data's ProjectionOperation along with mongoTemplate. I keep getting the following error.
`ProjectionOperation projectStage = new ProjectionOperation().andExclude("locations.datacenters.servers", "locations.datacenters.clusters.servers");`
`Exclusion of field locations.datacenters.servers not allowed. Projections by the mongodb aggregation framework only support the exclusion of the _id field!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible with `$elemMatch` to project the nested array element.

You can try the below aggregation in 3.4 server.

Use `$unwind` couple of times to reach the nested array and apply `$match` to pick the nested array element.

```
   db.summary.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "locations.datacenters._id": "dc1.1"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$locations"
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$locations.datacenters"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "locations.datacenters._id": "dc1.1"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "locations.datacenters.clusters.servers": 0
        }
      }
    ])
```

`{"$project": {"locations.datacenters.clusters.servers": 0}}` will remove the `servers` field while keep all the other fields in the final output.

From the docs

> If you specify the exclusion of a field other than _id, you cannot
>   employ any other $project specification forms: i.e. if you exclude
>   fields, you cannot also specify the inclusion of fields, reset the
>   value of existing fields, or add new fields.

Reference: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields

Comment: Thanks. It did gave me resources to figure out how to handle my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to project only the clusters field for datacenters dc1.1 then below query will do it.

```
db.summary.find({"locations.datacenters": {$elemMatch: {"id": "dc1.1"}}},{"locations.datacenters.clusters":1, _id : 0})
```

Note, the `_id:0` in projection is used to exclude the field _id to be displayed.

More information can be found at the following link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Nested Array, Push/Pull

```
 let doc = await Chat.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        $and: [
          {
            _id: chatId,
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                user: req.user.id,
              },
              {
                'messages.$.recipients': {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    id: recipientId
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          //@ts-ignore
          'messages.$.recipients': { id: recipientId },
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```