# how to work with nested objects in mongodb with python

Tags: python, arrays, json, mongodb

```
{
    "_id": 4545,
    "username": "testt",
    "data": {
        "passwords": [
            {
                "dataID": "175",
                "username": "enc_data",
                "password": "enc_data",
                "any": "enc_data",
                "any1": "enc_data",
                "any3": "enc_data"
            }
        ],
        "fav_list": []
    }
};
```

so I'm working on a project when I'll store the user encrypted data in a array inside of an object called 'data' so Ican have a nice organized data storing system but the problem here I can't really access the data from that nested object and I want to access the data with the 'dataID' and update it using the same id for each array object... I'm using python btw.
thanks for reading.

Comment: Not entirely sure about your problem here, but have you tried accessing "DataID" using for example --- print(data[passwords][dataID])

Comment: yeah i need to access the key to insert data in the database the print is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongo way of doing this is using [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters), this let's you update an array element by using a query, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
{
  "$set": {
    "data.passwords.$[element].property_to_set": "new property value"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.dataID": dataID
    }
  ],
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WdeoTLgpIXI)

And with `pymongo`:

```
collection.update_many(
{},
{
  "$set": {
    "data.passwords.$[element].property_to_set": "new property value"
  }
},
"array_filters"=[{"element.dataID": dataID}]
)
```

Comment: Thanks. that what i was looking for but can u help me with something else i need to query all the data from an array object too using the field of dataID. the $elemMatch not working on a nested field i get that error when use that code db.COLLECTION.find({_id:4545},{'data.passwords':{$elemMatch:{dataID:'175'}}})

Comment: Sure, If you could specify exactly what is the query and output result you want

Comment: i want to provide the object _id and then head to the data object and the passwords array cause every time i'll insert into the passwords array it will have that unique dataID inside of it like i showed in the schema so i want to grab that object from the passwords array using the dataID.

Comment: You can't use the projection `$elemMatch` like that, read a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46670813/10770370).

Comment: i tried this solution but didn't work the way i wanted it just gets everything.. i only want to get one object from an array using the dataID key inside that data object 
like i want to get the dataID : '175' which will get me the username and password etc for that specific object  inside the array.. is this even possible?

Comment: You can try it like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yB6aetoHZaj) using `$filter`.

Answer (score 0):

I removeed the [] of the passwords

```py
data1={
    "_id": 4545,
    "username": "testt",
    "data": {
        "passwords": {
            "dataID": "175",
            "username": "enc_data",
            "password": "enc_data",
            "any": "enc_data",
            "any1": "enc_data",
            "any3": "enc_data"
        },
        "fav_list": []
    }
}
res=data1['data']['passwords']['dataID']
print(res)
# 175

# modify existing data
res=data1['data']['passwords']['dataID']=200
print(res)
# 200

# insert new key
res=data1['data']['passwords']['new_var']=6
print(data1['data']['passwords'].keys())
# dict_keys(['dataID', 'username', 'password', 'any', 'any1', 'any3', 'new_var'])
```

Comment: ok this is good for access the dataID but what if i want to insert data in the passwords array inside that data object

Comment: actually this is good way to handle the data in the python file but i want to update the data in the mongodb too so i used that code and it worked db.COLLECTION.update({_id:4545},{$push:{'data.passwords':{username : 'testnew'}}})
this will insert a new data but u got the idea i'm now trying to fetch data using the same mechanics